# I have a list that returns two values at one position of the array

Tags: python, arrays, lis

I have a list that returns two values at one position of the array.
In the example is the 0 position of the array c.
I want to know how to retrieve the first value and then the second value

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c[0]` takes the first pair in your array.

If you want the first item of the first pair, you can just use `c[0][0]` and `c[0][1]` for the second.